# IndentationError: unexpected unindent

Tags: python, python-3.x

Started coding not too long ago, around a month or so. I'm currently coding a bot for Discord and everything was working fine until I got this error message when trying to run the bot after adding in new commands to it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jeriel\Desktop\JerryBot\run.py", line 162, in main
    from musicbot import MusicBot
  File "C:\Users\Jeriel\Desktop\JerryBot\musicbot\__init__.py", line 1, in <modu
le>
    from .bot import MusicBot
  File "C:\Users\Jeriel\Desktop\JerryBot\music\bot.py", line 2094
    if __name__ == "__main__":
                             ^
IndentationError: unexpected unindent
```

It started after I added this in. I checked every line before these and I couldn't find a single unindent anywhere:

```
    async def kick(message,*args):
        """Kicks the specified user from the server"""
        if len(message.mentions) < 1:
            return False

        if message.channel.is_private:
            msg = await client.send_message(message.channel,'Users cannot be kicked/banned from private channels.')
            asyncio.ensure_future(message_timeout(msg, 40))
            return

        if not message.channel.permissions_for(message.server.get_member(client.user.id)).kick_members:
            msg = await client.send_message(message.channel, message.author.mention + ', I do not have permission to kick users.')
            asyncio.ensure_future(message_timeout(msg, 40))
            return

        members = []

        if not message.channel.is_private and message.channel.permissions_for(message.author).kick_members:
            for member in message.mentions:
                if member != message.author:
                    try:
                        await client.kick(member)
                        members.append(member.name)
                    except:
                        pass
                else:
                    msg = await client.send_message(message.channel, message.author.mention + ', You should not kick yourself from a channel, use the leave button instead.')
                    asyncio.ensure_future(message_timeout(msg, 40))
        else:
            msg = await client.send_message(message.channel, message.author.mention + ', I do not have permission to kick users, or this is a private message channel.')
            asyncio.ensure_future(message_timeout(msg, 40))

        msg = await client.send_message(message.channel,'Successfully kicked user(s): `{}`'.format('`, `'.join(members)))
        asyncio.ensure_future(message_timeout(msg, 60))

    @register('ban','@<mention users>',owner=True)

    async def ban(message,*args):
        """Bans the specified user from the server"""
        if len(message.mentions) < 1:
            return False

        if message.channel.is_private:
            msg = await client.send_message(message.channel,'Users cannot be kicked/banned from private channels.')
            asyncio.ensure_future(message_timeout(msg, 40))
            return

        if not message.channel.permissions_for(message.server.get_member(client.user.id)).ban_members:
            msg = await client.send_message(message.channel, message.author.mention + ', I do not have permission to ban users.')
            asyncio.ensure_future(message_timeout(msg, 40))
            return

        members = []

        if message.channel.permissions_for(message.author).ban_members:
            for member in message.mentions:
                if member != message.author:
                    try:
                        await client.ban(member)
                        members.append(member.name)
                    except:
                        pass
                else:
                    msg = await client.send_message(message.channel, message.author.mention + ', You should not ban yourself from a channel, use the leave button instead.')
                    asyncio.ensure_future(message_timeout(msg, 40))
        else:
            msg = await client.send_message(message.channel, message.author.mention + ', I do not have permission to ban users, or this is a private message channel.')
            asyncio.ensure_future(message_timeout(msg, 40))

        msg = await client.send_message(message.channel,'Successfully banned user(s): `{}`'.format('`, `'.join(members)))
        asyncio.ensure_future(message_timeout(msg, 30))

    @register('bans',alias='bannedusers')
    @register('bannedusers')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot = JerryBot()
    bot.run("---")
```

Comment: The error message is pointing at `if __name__ == "__main__":`. Why is that line unindented relative to the rest of the code?

Comment: Did you copy and paste your code in, or type it in yourself? If you copy and pasted it, it may be due to an issue where you are using tabs to indent in some places, and spaces to indent in others. Doing that always does funny stuff...

Comment: @Blorgbeard I think the OP wants to use the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block to act as the main function, and if so then it must be un-indented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem's here:

```
    @register('bans',alias='bannedusers')
    @register('bannedusers')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot = JerryBot()
    bot.run("---")
```

Decorator syntax requires a function definition under the `@` line, which must be at the same indentation level as the `@`. You can't have your `if` statement there, in other words. You need a function definition. The indentation is just the first issue it caught; if you indent your `if` statement, you get a different error.

I can't tell whether you included the `@` lines in error here or if you omitted a function definition you meant to place there. Either write the function or remove the `@` lines, as suits your purpose.

Comment: Thanks for that! 

I did just that and it seemed to fix the indentation issue, however as soon as I did that, this appeared:

`File "C:\Users\Jeriel\Desktop\JerryBot\musicbot\bot.py", line 2018
    async def kick(message,*args):
                                 ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

C:\Users\Jeriel\Desktop\JerryBot>`

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you mixed tabs and spaces? This is a common error for beginners with python. Technically, you can use either but cannot mix them. My solution for this (I use vim as an IDE) is to set the tab key to actually be 4 spaces in my .vimrc.

You could try re-indeting in vim by typing `gg=G` and pressing enter in command mode.